# Reducing the number of series plotted gives console error

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, dygraphs

I'm using Dygraphs in an AngularJS application to show time series plots of data from a data-logger. Angular handles retrieving new data and updating the graph series when the data arrives, and Dygraphs is updating the plots nicely using an Angular `$watch()`. The problem arises when I want to switch to a different set of data, specifically one that contains fewer series. I see a console error (using Safari 5.1.9 on OS X 10.6.8):

```
'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'this.series_[b].yAxis')
```

at line 2 of `dygraph-combined.js`. Nothing untoward seems to happen, and the graph updates correctly, but I'd rather it didn't happen!

I had a few problems getting Angular to switch the graph data source correctly: what worked for me is to change the data source inside a `$timeout(,0)` call, while changing the other options immediately. This means that there will be a (brief) mismatch between the number of series, and the number of series titles and/or axes. If the number of series doesn't change, or increases, I don't get this error. Can anyone see what is going wrong, and advise me on how it can be avoided?

I've written an Angular directive to instantiate a Dygraph:

```
'use strict';
angular.module('dygraphs', []);

angular.module('dygraphs').directive('mrhDygraph', function ($parse, $q) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        replace: true,
        scope: {data: '=', initialOptions: '@', options: '='},
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            var dataArrived = $q.defer();
            dataArrived.promise.then(function (graphData) {
                scope.graph = new Dygraph(element[0], graphData, $parse(scope.initialOptions)(scope.$parent));
                return graphData.length - 1;
            }).then(function(lastPoint) {
                scope.graph.setSelection(lastPoint);
                scope.$emit('dygraphCreated', element[0].id, scope.graph);
            });
            var removeInitialDataWatch = scope.$watch('data', function (newValue, oldValue, scope) {
                if ((newValue !== oldValue) && (newValue.length > 0)) {
                    dataArrived.resolve(newValue);
                    removeInitialDataWatch();
                    scope.$watch('data', function (newValue, oldValue, scope) {
                        if ((newValue !== oldValue) && (newValue.length > 0)) {
                            var selection = scope.graph.getSelection();
                            scope.graph.updateOptions({'file': newValue});
                            if ((selection >= 0) && (selection < newValue.length)) {
                                scope.graph.setSelection(selection);
                            }
                        }
                    }, true);
                    scope.$watch('options', function (newValue, oldValue, scope) {
                        if (newValue !== undefined) {
                            scope.graph.updateOptions(newValue);
                        }
                    }, true);
                }
            }, true);
        }
    };
});
```

and then in my controller, I switch graph data sources like this:

```
$scope.setGraphDataSource = function (plotData, sourceData, scaleFactor) {
    $timeout(function () {
            $scope[plotData] = [];
            for (series in removeWatch) {
                removeWatch[series]();
            }
            removeWatch = [];
            var col = 0;
            for (series in sourceData) {
                removeWatch[series] = function (col) {
                    return $scope.$watch(function () {return $scope.logs[sourceData[col]].data.length},
                    function (newValue, oldValue, scope) {
                        updateCol(plotData, col, scope, scope.logs[sourceData[col]],
                                    sourceData.length + 1, scaleFactor[col]);
                    })}(col);
                col = col + 1;
            }
        }, 0);
}

$scope.showTemperatureGraph = function () {
    $scope.setGraphDataSource('graphData', ['OutsideTemperature', 'InsideTemperature'], [1, 1]);
    $scope.graphOptions = {labels: ['Time', 'Outside', 'Inside'],
        series: {'Inside': {axis: 'y'}, 'Outside': {axis: 'y'}},
        axes: {x: {valueFormatter: function (ms) {return $filter('date')(new Date(ms), 'dd/MM HH:mm')}},
               y: {valueFormatter: function (num) {return num.toFixed(1)}}
            },
        xlabel: 'Local Time', ylabel: 'Temperature (ºC)', stepPlot: false};
};
```

Any suggestions, comments, or even answers would be welcome!

Thanks

Comment: Hi....did this problem get resolved for you? If possible, can you share the code for angular directive that you created for dygraphs?

Comment: This issue is still in limbo. I've not been working on the project for a while, and as it wasn't a showstopper bug, we have ignored it! The code for the directive is in the question, above. Please feel free to use it!

Answer (score 0):

It's possible the series are not matching up correctly. When you update the graph, what is the the existing values of g.getOption("labels")? Do you provide a new set of labels? What format is the input data? Is it CSV? If so, does it have a header?

Comment: I'm providing data as a native Javascript Array. Because of the way I'm using Angular data-binding, the changes to the 'file' option (i.e. the new data) and the remaining options, including the new series labels, do not occur at the same time, so for a short period there are fewer chart series than there are series labels. I suspect this is the cause of the problem: I'm just surprised it should give an error like this. It doesn't seem to cause any major problems.

Comment: This may be a Dumb Question (TM) but how would I go about getting a non-minified version of dygraphs off Github? What files do I need? I'd like to investigate the problem in more depth if I get time (this is a spare time project for me!)